# vectors in a plane of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, plane-geometry

Can three vectors in a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ be linearly independent? I believe the answer is no because in order to be on the plane they would have to be similar to the normal vector of the plane. For example I found a contradiction to this statement in the plane

$$z = x + y + w$$

with vectors:

$$[-1, 1, 1]$$

$$[1, -1, 0] $$

$$[0, 0, 1]$$

However I am unsure whether this applies to all vectors on the plane $\mathbb{R}^3$, although I am leaning more towards it is false.

Comment: Are you restricted to planes through the origin only, i.e., to vector subspaces of $\mathbb R^3$? If not, then then answer is “yes.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **plane** in $\mathbb{R^3}$ is a **subspace of dimension 2** therefore you can't have more than 2 vectors in the plane linearly independent.

Another way to see that is consider that a plane is defined by **one equation** with **tre variables**

$$ax+by+cz=d$$

thus **only two variables are free** thus the dimension is 2.